# Getting indexes of rows to delete where two columns are zero

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

Here are my columns :

```
'CD Block_Code','Total Population Female','Illiterate Female','Total/Rural/Urban'
```

I want to remove rows where either total female population is zero or illiterate female is zero.

## Code

```
df_cleaned = df.copy(deep = True)

entry_to_remove = [] ;

for index, col in  df.iterrows():

    if (col['Total Population Female'] == '0') or col['Illiterate Female'] == '0':      
        entry_to_remove.append(index)   

    print("entry_to_remove: {}".format(len(entry_to_remove)))

df_cleaned.drop(entry_to_remove, axis = 0, inplace = True)

df_cleaned.head(3)
```

When I am running the last code, it is giving me zero rows, in actual only 634 ones are zero.

So there will be 4 clusters, I want to get data for all 4 clusters 
    separately and do further analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier way to do this would be with indexing, using 2 conditions:

```
df[(df['Illiterate Female']!=0) & (df['Total Population Female']!=0)]
```

Example:

```
>>> df
   CD Block_Code  Illiterate Female  Total Population Female
0              0                  1                        1
1              0                  1                        1
2              0                  1                        0
3              0                  0                        1

>>> df[(df['Illiterate Female']!=0) & (df['Total Population Female']!=0)]
   CD Block_Code  Illiterate Female  Total Population Female
0              0                  1                        1
1              0                  1                        1
```

You could also filter based on the underlying `numpy` arrays, which may be faster for large dataframes, but admittedly less readable:

```
df[(df[['Illiterate Female','Total Population Female']].values != 0).all(1)]

   CD Block_Code  Illiterate Female  Total Population Female
0              0                  1                        1
1              0                  1                        1
```

Comment: Ok, this works well.But how to store the indexes in the list entry_to_remove. I am getting 634 rows which is correct , but while trying to drop I am losing all data

Comment: You can reverse the conditions and get the index: `df[~((df['Illiterate Female']!=0) & (df['Total Population Female']!=0))].index`

Comment: Thanks, both solutions are working. Can you look at the if condition I wrote and then trying to store indexes, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, if they're stored as strings. Otherwise, remove the quotation marks: `'0'` should be `0`